# PHImageManager maximum target size not working in Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, phimagemanager

I have the following code in my GMImagePickerController in FinishedPicking Event.

```
picker.FinishedPickingAssets += (s, args) =>
        {
            PHImageManager imageManager = new PHImageManager();
            PHImageRequestOptions imageOptions = new PHImageRequestOptions();
            imageOptions.DeliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode.HighQualityFormat;
            imageOptions.ResizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeMode.Exact;
            foreach (var asset in args.Assets)
            {
                imageManager.RequestImageForAsset(asset,
                  new CGSize(asset.PixelWidth,asset.PixelHeight),
                  PHImageContentMode.Default,
                  imageOptions,
                  (image1, info) =>
                  {
                      if(count<1)
                      {
                          CommonFunction.AttachPhotoiOS(image1, eventRecordID, cp, "NormalImage");
                          count++;
                      }
                      //CallCommonFunctionAttachPhotoiOS(image1, eventRecordID);
                  });
                break;
            }
        };
```

As you can see I have already set the CGSize to the asset width and height, but still, when I debug and mouse over the image1 which is the retrieved image, the width and height is always 90 x 120 but not the original size of the asset. I have tried many ways and many images, the width and height seems like fixed forever. Which part has been done wrong? How can I get the original size of the image from it?

Comment: do NOT post code as images.  Take the time to paste the code as text and format it

Comment: Try to set `PHImageContentMode.Default` to `PHImageContentMode.AspectFill` .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT unfortunately not working...

Comment: What is the  original size of the asset ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT 1125 x 2001 px

Comment: Could you share a sample so that I can test it on my side (your code works fine in my project ).

Comment: How can I do that? Like paste all the code here?

Comment: Upload your sample to github .

Comment: And you could try to set the CGSize as static like new CGSize(200,300) to check if the image1 still return 90*120 .

Comment: I wish I could but my project contains some confidential data. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, even though I have set static number, it still the same.

Comment: Or you could post the full code .

Comment: It's ok, I add another line of code to resize the image again. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: You could post the solution and accept it , which will hel p more people .